# Getting ImportError no module named arcpy when importing into PythonWin?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.6, pythonwin, importerror

Here is the error i get when i use the import arcpy command in pythonwin:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
>   1, in  ImportError: No module named arcpy

Can any one tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like the arcpy module isn't saved to your PYTHONPATH or sys.path.  Does it work within ArcMap's Python Window?

Comment: Yes i does work inside the Arc10 Arcpy interface

Answer (score 4):

Check whether you are using the correct version of Python.

My install of ArcGIS 10.1 installed and uses python 2.7, and it looks like you are using 2.6, so it may be the case that ArcPy has not been installed for this version of python.

Typically python is installed in the root of your main hard drive, so you can check for a second version of python there.